# SOLR error: Multi-valued field XXX should be mapped to either List or Set types

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, multivalue

I'm trying to create a SOLR core and getting this error message:

```
Multi-valued field md5checksum should be mapped to either List or Set types
```

I don't understand it, because my schema specifically says multiValued="false" for field md5checksum:

```
<schema name="solr_catalogrecord" version="1.0">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"/>
  <fieldType name="uuid" class="solr.UUIDField"/>
 </types>
  <fields>
    <field name="id"  type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="md5checksum"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"  docValues="true" multiValued="false"/>
  </fields>
  <defaultSearchField>md5checksum</defaultSearchField>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

In case it makes a difference, I'm running SOLR inside DataStax Enterprise.

Comment: Has the field been multivalued at some point in time? (i.e. can there be documents in the index where the field is multivalued?) Is the field in DataStax a List or Set (I'm not familiar with DataStax, but it seems to be a DataStax error message - maybe it's complaining about it not being multi-valued)?

Comment: Field was never multivalued and is not a List or Set in DataStax.  I changed the schema version, per suggestion from sbtourist, and that did the trick.  Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solr schema version 1.0 has all field types multivalued by default, please set the latest schema version (1.5).